# Are all instance variables in an entity class persistent in the database?

Tags: java, jpa, entity, persistence

Are all instance variables in an entity class persistent in the database? Or is it possible for some variables in the entity to be non-persistent?

Comment: Of course, use transient annotation keyword .

Comment: By default they are persistent. If you add `@Transient` annotation on a variable, it is non-persistent.

Comment: There are many JPA API docs on the internet and they will ALL explain this. Perhaps read them? For example http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#member_transient

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can with using of `@Transient` annotation. For example :

```
class MyClass{

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Transient
    private int identity;
}
```

Here, `identity` field is transient and not persistent in the database.

> This means if a variable is marked `@Transient` then it won't be added
>   in the database. it has no persistence representation of this variable
>   in that hibernate session. After the session is closed these transient
>   objects will be destroyed by garbage collection.